# How to use listner inside a BroadCastRecievever?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have to display number of times device is unlocked with a textView which is inside my Activity.
I am storing the unlock frequency in Prefrences with BroadCast Reciever USER_ACTIVE onReciever().

I want to update the Activity textView everyTime i recieve the User_Active broadcast.

Any leads?

Comment: What seems to problem here ?

Comment: create broadcast receiver inside you activity. And broadcast the count numbers to your activity's receiver. You should understand enough how android components communicate each others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple three steps:

1. Create a runtime broadcast receiver with your own action(Ex: UPDATED_TEXT_PREFERENCES).
2. Register/unregister for broadcast  in `onStart()` and `onStop()`
3. On your `USER_ACTIVE onReciever().` send a broadcast with the own action you have created(Ex: UPDATED_TEXT_PREFERENCES)
4. On your activity onReceive you can update your textview.

Comment below for any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a interface that your activity implements and use this listener in your broadcast or where you write in the preference